# Copy voice messages from iPhone

Tags: iphone

How can I copy voice messages from Phone (not text or log information) from an iPhone 4 to a computer so you can listen back to them?

I am a songwriter and the only was I was able to save some songs on a moment's notice was to call myself up and leave them as messages which I have renewed, some for over a year. This was before I found out about Voice Memos, which I would also like to transfer. I can record with a mic from the phone but the volume is very low.

Answer (score 2):

Try this app - http://www.ecamm.com/mac/phoneview/

It copies all the info you mentioned to a Mac. Free trial to be sure you like it before paying.

If this is one time (or your value of the time it takes to manually record these is less than $30), just hook a stereo plug from the phone to the computer and record the mic input on the Mac. (Or PC if you use that computer)

Comment: I'd personally just go with the cord method if I needed to do this. It may be worth mentioning that Audacity is a great free program to record on the computer side.